# How to create a Git repo as a tarfile from Django project?

Tags: django, git

I want to turn a Django project into a zipfile that I store as a Git repository so that I can use that repo as a template for other projects.  If I do that, the Django docs say I can use this command to generate new projects:

```
django-admin.py startapp --template=https://github.com/githubuser/django-app-template/archive/master.zip myapp
```

What I don't understand is how to create that zipfile as a repo.  If my project is named "django-app-template," am I supposed to create a subdirectory called "archive" and then create a "master.zip" file inside it?  If so, how do I create that zipfile using "git archive" and "tar"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the zip file yourself; GitHub provides that functionality for you.

GitHub provides the `github.com/username/projectname/archive/master.zip` link to download a zip file of your project.

Comment: I don't want to use the browser.  I want to pull a compressed Django project template from my Git repo using my CLI.